# C# modem-phone integration

Tags: c#

Is there any way to manipulate a phone in c#?
I have a modem, the modem is connected to the phone and the phone is connected to the pc, I want to make an app, that shows the number of the incoming call?
I know this is a longshot, but still, any ideas?

Comment: These features are not provided by modems. Modems are merely digital-analog converters to allow computers to communicate with each other over phone lines. Obtaining that information from your phone will require hardware support; contact your phone vendor for more information.

Comment: @CodyGray there are a number of POTS modems that actually support CalledID and will send out that number in the `RING` response...  Mind you, POTS, Plain Old Telephone, I'm not referring to cell modems here.

Comment: Close-voters: please reread the question again, you seem to have missed the point that Kristaps states clearly that he wants to make an application in C# to read caller id.  So I really don't see why his question can be not programming related and/or too broad.

Comment: @fvu There are too many assumptions that need to be made in order to answer the question. It is therefore not reasonably-scoped and difficult to answer in a Q&A format like this one. That's why I think it is "too broad". There is no doubt about its being programming-related, of course; I didn't miss the C# tag. I simply think the question needs to have more specifics/details added to it before it is re-opened to start accumulating answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that we are

- talking about a conventional modem here
- interfaced via a serial port to the modem (that is, to the computer it ***looks*** like a COM port)
- which supports caller ID (see your modem's doc which you will need anyways to figure out what the RING response with caller ID looks like, and what command you need to send to the modem to activate CalledID - common strings include `AT#CID=2` `AT%CCID=1` or `AT%CCID=2` according to [this page](http://www2.mtnsys.com:81/pages/howto/htmdmtst.htm)
- the implemented CalledID system is compatible with your provider's system, and your subscription includes CallerID service

As you can see, a serious set of preconditions...

Most of these can be quickly tested by hooking up the modem to the phone line and opening HyperTerminal or any other terminal emulator on it.  When you receive a call on the phone line, you should see `RING` followed by information of the calling party.  How that information is structured depends on the individual modem, you should be able to find that info in the documentation or just by looking at the output.

Once you're this far the rest is more or less trivial: you open the appropriate COM port using .net's included SerialPort class (tutorial [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Serial-Port-Programming-With-NET/), many others floating around) and program the following sequence:

- initialize the modem by sending

  - `ATZ` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - wait for `OK`
  - send caller ID command <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  - wait for `OK`
- loop over

  - keep on reading the serial port until you see `RING` followed by the caller's ID
  - output the data

Only in very rare conditions you have to reset the modem between calls, for many modems it may help to wake them up by pulling DTR low for a second and then back up before sending `ATZ`, some modems even automatically initialize when DTR is pulse like that.

So all in all it's pretty simple, but as intefacing with modems has become a whole less popular than it used to be you'll need to do some digging to find relevant information and sample code.  Good luck!